# Drupal Password set

Tags: drupal-7

I have to reset my password direct through database for that I used query

UPDATE users SET pass = md5('NEWPASSWORD') WHERE name = 'admin'

but still I am not able to login.

Can you please tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With drupal 7, password are no more encrypted through md5.

There are several way to reset a password in drupal7.

**Using drush** :

```
drush upwd admin --password="newpassword"
```

**Without drush, if you have a cli access to the server :**

```
cd <drupal root directory>
php scripts/password-hash.sh 'myPassword'
```

Now copy the resultant hash and paste it into the query:

```
update users set name='admin', pass='pasted_big_hash_from_above' where uid=1;
```

**If you are working on a remote environment** on which you cannot connect, you can put this specified code in a file such as password.php such as this one:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
  require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
  require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/password.inc';
  print _password_crypt('sha512', $_GET['p'], _password_generate_salt(DRUPAL_HASH_COUNT));
  exit();
}
print "No password to hash.";
```

And then hit your site using: http://domain.tld/password.php?p=MyPassword. The hash will appear on your browser's tab.
  Don't forget to remove it once you done it.

Comment: Thanks.. I have tried second option and it get work.. please remove ''(quotes) around MyPassword..in http://domain.tld/password.php?p='MyPassword'.. because password get save with these quotes

Answer (score 0):

Are you locked out of your account? If you've got DB access then try clearing out the "flood" table.